# Kubernetes kubectl bash completion with alias

Tags: kubernetes

I am using `kubectl with bash completion` , but I prefer to use a shorter alias for `kubectl` such as `ks` , what changes I need to make to get the bash completion work with alias `ks`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*A more recent update from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#bash):*

- Source the completion script in your ~/.bashrc file:

  ```bash
  echo 'source <(kubectl completion bash)' >>~/.bashrc
  ```
- Add the completion script to the /etc/bash_completion.d directory:

  ```bash
  kubectl completion bash >/etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
  ```

If you have an alias for kubectl, you can extend shell completion to work with that alias:

```bash
echo 'alias ks=kubectl' >>~/.bashrc
echo 'complete -F __start_kubectl ks' >>~/.bashrc
```

You can basically do this:

```
$ echo "source <(kubectl completion bash | sed 's|__start_kubectl kubectl|__start_kubectl ks|g') >> ~/.bashrc
```

*Out of date*:

A slight change from what is described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#on-linux-using-bash).

In essence, you are substituting the following in the `kubectl completion bash` output:

```
if [[ $(type -t compopt) = "builtin" ]]; then
    complete -o default -F __start_kubectl kubectl
else
    complete -o default -o nospace -F __start_kubectl kubectl
fi
```

With this:

```
if [[ $(type -t compopt) = "builtin" ]]; then
    complete -o default -F __start_kubectl ks
else
    complete -o default -o nospace -F __start_kubectl ks
fi
```

Comment: What if I want completion for a 'composite alias' in bash, like I have set an alias 'kdry' which resolves to 'kubectl --dry-run=client'. But typing <tab> after kdry in bash offers no autocompletion. Why? 
(Note: This does work in zsh.)

Comment: There is an error in
`echo 'complete -F __start_kubectl k' >>~/.bashrc`    
Should be `ks` not `k`.

Answer (score 66):

from the official docs

```
# after installing bash completion

alias k=kubectl
complete -F __start_kubectl k
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#bash

Comment: This solution is way less hacky than the one deemed "correct".

Comment: Could not understand why the alias did not work with auto-completion. This helped. Thanks.

Comment: k is King! Much prefer k for alias than anything else.

Answer (score 11):

I have this in my .bashrc to get alias and auto completion.

> source <(kubectl completion bash | sed s/kubectl/k/g)

Comment: This might generate a lot of code if we are having so many aliases. Is there any efficient alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Just to complement the awnser of **endline** (his solution works just works in **active session of shell**, if you close, you have to **reexecute**) and maybe help someone with the same trouble I was getting.

You can add it to the shell **permanently** using the structure above from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-autocomplete)

**echo 'alias k=kubectl' >>~/.bashrc**      (add alias to shell)

**echo 'source <(kubectl completion bash)' >>~/.bashrc** (add completion)

**echo 'complete -F __start_kubectl k' >>~/.bashrc**    (make them work together)

So, now you can execute commands like 'k get logs -n my-namespace -f my-p[TAB]' (to complete name of pod for example) even if close and open a new session.

Answer (score 0):

I found that existing kubernetes aliases still require typing many arguments, especially when working across namespaces.

I wrote this tiny utility that has been working well for me in terms of reducing kubectl 'typing stress'. It does not cover all the commands but it is easy to extend:

https://github.com/bhakta0007/kube-alias

Answer (score 0):

1. first **run** below command

   ```
   sudo kubectl completion bash > /etc/bash_completion.d/kubectl
   ```
2. and **add** this at the end of **.bashrc**

   ```
   source /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
   source /etc/bash_completion
   source <(kubectl completion bash)
   alias k=kubectl
   complete -F __start_kubectl k
   ```
3. **restart your shell**

Comment: There's `~/.bash_aliases` for alias k=kubectl